# Shrink iframe margins

Tags: reactjs, vimeo

I embedded a Vimeo video in my page using @u-wave/react-vimeo. 
The iframe seems to be taking up much more room than the actual video box, and it is taking up much of my viewport. 
This is the entire video code:

```
   <Vimeo
                id = 'Vimeo'
                video="https://vimeo.com/..."
                autoplay
                width={800}
                height={600}
                paused={this.props.videoIsPaused}
                onTimeUpdate= {e=> this.props.getVideoTime(e)}
            />
```

How do I shrink the margins around the video box?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to CSS:

```
iframe {
  height: 480px;
}
```